# Displaying the username of current user (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

Is it possible to display the username of the current user in a macOS app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let userName = NSUserName()
let fullUserName = NSFullUserName()
```

Comment: On iPhone "NSFullUserName()" gives me "Mobile User".

Comment: ... and on the simulator (iOS 15) both are empty...

Comment: Has Apple considered this a privacy issue at any point?

Comment: confirm both empty on iOS 17 beta

Answer (score 27):

You can use the `NSUserName()` function:

```
var username = NSUserName()!
```

Comment: ! not needed in Swift 3

Answer (score 1):

The following did work for me. It was copied from [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/52074?answerId=154923022#154923022).

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
    CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID { (record, error) in
        CKContainer.default().discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID: record!, completionHandler: { (userID, error) in
            let fullName = (userID?.nameComponents?.givenName)! + " " + (userID?.nameComponents?.familyName)!
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: in iOS 17 You can see a warning: requestApplicationPermission(_:completionHandler:)' was deprecated in iOS 17.0: No longer supported. Please see Sharing CloudKit Data with Other iCloud Users.