# Getting the current user name in Swift 4

Tags: swift4

In Swift 3, you could do this to get the name of the current user:

```
var username = NSUserName()
```

as was explained here: [Getting the username of actual user in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045814/getting-the-username-of-actual-user-in-swift)

But in Swift 4 it only returns a blank string without any error, when executed in a playground.  What is the correct way to do it in Swift 4?

Comment: var username = NSUserName()
print(username)  // works fine in xcode project

Comment: FYI, the playground returns a blank string. Try with  XCode cocoa project

Comment: Same here. My case running with the Emulator. I dont have now an iPhone to test. Is that expected in that case?